# What is the difference between tissue engineering and 3D bioprinting?

Tags: cell-biology, human-physiology, biotechnology

3D bioprinting is the modified version of the tissue engineering but when we want to describe the both terms, what are the basic criteria or points to make difference between these?

Answer (score 1):

Tissue engineering is research into ways of organizing cells and cell droplet/matrix structures into a useful form, usually for medical applications. In the near future, tissue engineering could refer to rewriting or genetically modifying cells for a new purpose or to enhance their existing function. Even more into the future and tissue engineering could mean custom-building multi-cell structures from scratch on a computer.

3D bioprinting is the practical or laboratory deployment of the first technology mentioned above - a subset of tissue engineering.

In a nutshell:

Tissue engineering = "Come up with a creative way to arrange these cells and cell structures into something useful".

3D bioprinting = "Use the above-mentioned technology to build part of a synthetic organ".